# named function assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, function

While I was doing a test I came across below function. can someone describe this f and g status. Is there any special scenarios we have to use this.

```
var f = function g(){ return "confused"; };
```

Comment: where do these variables occur?

Comment: This is a function expression, and `g` is unnecessary: *"Can be omitted, in which case the function is anonymous. The name is only local to the function body"* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).